# Excel VBA Macro - Insert copied range of cells in between every row of selection in excel

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I need some help on my homework.
I have 2 worksheets.
The first worksheet looks something like this

[image]

Second worksheet looks something like this.

[image]

I need to copy from the first worksheet and insert to the second worksheet.
Output looks something like this:

[image]

I am currently stuck now. This is  my current codes:

```
Sub insertabc(LastRow As Long)
MsgBox LastRow

For i = 1 To LastRow
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
Next i
          
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the copied data supposed to start at B instead of A?

Comment: Hi Yes, it is starts from B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things you should pay attention to:

- When iterating with a for-loop, you should (normally) use it to go through a range/array/set, i.e. `Range("A" & i)`
- You should fully qualify which range you're talking about including the sheet, i.e. `Dim rngInsert As Range: Set rngInsert = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("First")`
- Using variables is easier to use down the line, i.e. `Dim rng As Range : Set rng = Selection` (but don't forget next point)
- Selection is almost never necessary so [try to avoid as much as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), this will prevent issues and increase performance: `Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws2.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)` with ws2: `Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkboook.Worksheets("Second")` (Second is just the name of the worksheet)
- When adding/deleting rows, work backwards so the iteration works as intended.

For you that could look like this:

```
Sub copyValuesInBetween()
    Dim ws1 As WorkSheet, ws2 As WorkSheet
    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("First")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Second")
    lRow = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = lRow To 2 Step -1 'backwards looping
        ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(1,1).Resize(,3).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i-1).Resize(,3).Value 
        'give values instead of copying
        'i-1 for ws1 since you have them starting at Row1 and in sheet2 at Row2
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that this won't check for selection or copy from sheet1 but it will get the result you showed :)

Comment: Question: if the copied data starts at C, I have to update Offset(1,1) to Offset(1,2) right?

Comment: Question: if the copied data increased to D, I have to update the Resize(,3) to Resize(,4)?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Do note that you could automate it further rather than hardcode by checking how many columns are used but in a small example exercise as this one, I didn't see a need for it.